# Tips on reshaping data, pivot-like?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a table of levels and years that looks roughly like this:

```
INSERT INTO demo(first_name, rank, year) AS VALUES
  ('Peter',2,2017), ('Robert',3,2016), ('Evelyn',2,2017), 
  ('Rand',3,2017), ('Kofi',3,2017), ('Daniel',3,2016), ('Leonard',1,2017),
  ('Mary',1,2017), ('Frank',1,2017), ('John',3,2017), ('Mary',1,2016), 
  ('Gilbert',3,2016), ('Quince',2,2017), ('David',3,2017), ('Louis',2,2017),
  ('Felipe',2,2016), ('Alfonso',1,2017), ('Elise',3,2016), ('Jorge',3,2017),
  ('Mary',3,2016), ('Jasvant',2,2017), ('Paul',3,2017), ('Richard',2,2017),
  ('Christopher',2,2017), ('Johannes',2,2016), ('Nasser',3,2016), ('Bruce',3,2017), 
  ('John',3,2016), ('Frederic',3,2016);
```

I can capture totals for each level and year with a pretty basic `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT  rank, COUNT(*), year
FROM demo
GROUP BY rank, year
ORDER BY year, rank;
```

That gives me a fairly tidy summary of the demo data:

```
Rank  Count  Year
1      1    2016
2      2    2016
3      8    2016
1      4    2017
2      7    2017
3      7    2017
```

My actual data is a lot bigger, and I'd like to be able to see it in a summary table that looks something more like this:

```
Rank    2016    2017
1         1     4
2         2     7
3         8     7
```

Is there a straightforward way to query a pivot-like view like this? For a much wider range of ranks and years?

Comment: have you looked at the crosstab function in postgres?

Comment: I have not. Sounds like I should. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query seems like it documents it well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pivot your data using crosstab, but as usual it requires a well-known column's name.

First you should install [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) module.

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Then you can call a crosstab with

```
SELECT * FROM 
  crosstab('SELECT rank, year::INT, COUNT(*)::INT ct FROM demo 
            GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1, 2') 
  AS ct(rk INT, "2016" INT, "2017" INT)
```

> ```
> rk | 2016 | 2017
> -: | ---: | ---:
>  1 |    1 |    4
>  2 |    2 |    7
>  3 |    8 |    7
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9fb810048ce3225feeb9721b2360ce0f)*

Comment: Getting quicker on those answers, fingers on fire today.

Comment: I also had to do `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;` as a privileged user.